# Select rows with same id but different value in other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sample data:

[image]

I want to get row 1, 5, and 10. I hope you could help me, Thanks.

Comment: This is a dump of screen captures.  Please edit your question, and include sample data and output which represents your problem.  As of right now, your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have distinct data based on different columnn data, you should use `GROUP BY` query.

If you have table called `tbl` which has column `field1`, `field2` and `field3` and you want to get all rows which has distinct data for all field in 'tbl', then your query should be like this :

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY field1, field2, field3
```

Comment: You need to specify, by which column, you want to get distinct row